# Spring UI - Overriding RegisterController password settings

Tags: grails, grails-2.3

I am using `grails 2.3.4` with `':spring-security-core:2.0-RC2'` and `":spring-security-ui:1.0-RC1"`.

I have my `RegisterController` ,which looks like that:

```
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.annotation.Secured;

    @Secured(['permitAll'])
    class RegisterController extends grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.RegisterController {

    }
```

I wanted to change the password settings by adding this at the end to my `config.groovy`:

```
//password validation of RegisterController.groovy
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.password.validationRegex='^([a-zA-Z0-9])$'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.password.minLength=8
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.password.maxLength=64
```

However, nothing has changed yet. I still get the same message when running my app.

Any recommendations what could be wrong?

**UPDATE**

Even though using this settings: Password is: `Test123@`

[image]

I cannot create a user. Any recommendations how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your settings are correct and should work.

Reading your questions, you say that the message is still the same. Is the validation still the same? Because the message should be set in the i18n files with the message code

```
command.password.error.strength
```

If it's only the message, this should do it.

Comment: If i understand correctly, my answer is still correct. The password you entered doesn't validate, according to your regex, so the fact that there is an error shown is correct. The message in red has nothing to do with the regex you chose. it is fixed in the i18n files. Change the text to your own string, and the message will be gone.

Comment: OK thx for your answer. What I do not understand is, `The password you entered doesn't validate` looking at the regex it should, in both cases(pls show me exactly whats wrong, if I am wrong with this!(I do not see it ;( )); `it is fixed in the i18n files`: This is what I also do not, because in the i18n file there is only a string. And this should not be called, if my regex would be correct...

Comment: Your validation regex is checking if the password contains numbers and letetrs only. I am no regex expert, but you are defining beginning and end to the regex, and only letters and numbers, therefore no special signs will be validated. the @ sign at the end of the password will make it not validate. About the message - the i18n file contains only a string. I would personally change it to something along the line of "Your password should contain letters and numbers only". something like that.

Comment: Thx a lot for your answer! What would be, in your opinion a valid passoword?

Comment: Hey, thx for your reply. I changed it to the local settings and it works great ;) Thx for your help!!!

Answer (score -1):

You have to change the message with key `command.password.error.strength` in:

```
your_application\target\work\plugins\spring-security-ui-1.0-RC2\grails-app\i18n\messages.spring-security-ui.properties. ​​​​​​
```